# Getting crash when calling CallWindowProc()

Tags: dll, crash, hook

In order to do some hooks on windows messages, I added a dll to the exe file.

```
result = isUnicodeWindow ? ::CallWindowProcW(wndProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam) : ::CallWindowProcA(wndProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return result;
```

But when CallWindowProcW is called in dll, it will cause crash, where the parameter is EVENT_OBJECT_HELPCHANGE.

I know my question is too general, but I really don't have any more information. Can anyone give me some advice, thank you very much.

My dll did not process EVENT_OBJECT_HELPCHANGE, but just called CallWindowProcW directly. But it caused a crash.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V59Hh.png)

Comment: What is `isUnicodeWindow`? You should call CallWindowProcA if you used SetWindowLongPtrA and CallWindowProcW if you used SetWindowLongPtrW.

Comment: bool isUnicodeWindow = (::IsWindowUnicode(hWnd) != FALSE);
 WNDPROC wndProc = isUnicodeWindow ? &::DefWindowProcW : &::DefWindowProcA;
There is no problem with these codes, which have been used in our production environment for a long time, but this event caused a crash. Other windows messages are no problem.

Comment: Do you also use `isUnicodeWindow` to decide whether to call the A or W version of SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr? Basically, Get/SetWindowLongPtr and CallWindowProc must match character sets